# why eclipse complains No grammar constraints while that schema is already in xml catalog

Tags: java, xml, eclipse

When I developing a custom jsp tag library, eclipse complains:

```
No grammar constraints (DTD or XML Schema) referenced in the document.
```

My tld file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<taglib version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_0.xsd">
    <tlib-version>2.0</tlib-version>
    <jsp-version>2.0</jsp-version>
    <short-name>gzbanking-taglib</short-name>
    <uri>http://www.cbrc.gov.cn/tag</uri>
    <description>
        贵州银行业服务实体经济信息平台系统自定义JSP标签库
    </description>

    <tag>
        <name>menus</name>
        <tag-class>gov.cbrc.gzbanking.view.tags.MenuTagSupport</tag-class>
        <body-content>empty</body-content>
    </tag>

    <tag>
        <name>userbar</name>
        <tag-class>gov.cbrc.gzbanking.view.tags.UserBarTagSupport</tag-class>
        <body-content>empty</body-content>
    </tag>
</taglib>
```

but I can find this entry in Preference >> XML >> XML Catalog:
[image]

And "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/" is also there

I am using tomcat 7.0 and my web project use servlet 2.5. 
Any one can help?

Comment: The xsi:schemaLocation value is missing half of the entry. It should be

`xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_0.xsd"`